# Why Gmail Meter is not working

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

I added Gmail Meter  to my Gmail account but it never reported anything. Do you know what could be the matter? I worked to authorize and add the script, then I waited and nothing happened. When I go to [gmailmeter.com](http://gmailmeter.com) the registration process starts over the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Ryan from the Gmail Meter team. Sorry to hear the reports aren't coming through. This is actually happening with a few of our users now, so you're not the only one.

Soon we hope to revamp the program with better features and of course better functionality. Please feel free to shoot me an email and I can personally keep you updated as Gmail Meter gets better.

ryan@shuttlecloud.com

Comment: This question is now the top search result on the subject, just FYI. Is there perhaps a fix as of now?

Comment: The issues with this don't seem to have been resolved yet.

Answer (score 5):

This is Eduardo from the ShuttleCloud & Gmail Meter team. We've recently updated Gmail Meter. If you have previously tried Gmail Meter but had problems with it, please try removing it and installing it again. Uninstalling Gmail Meter is not easy due to the underlying Google Apps Script code it's based on. Here are instructions to **uninstall** Gmail Meter:

1. When you signed up for Gmail Meter you received an email with uninstall instructions and a link to uninstall the script. Please start the uninstallation process by clicking the "Uninstall Gmail Meter" button. When the URL opens in your web browser click the "Uninstall" button. If you can't find the email, try this **[direct link](https://docs.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz3K7s6eRnMv_YdTjRPY4M_Mi0PhM3KhBOoZvgYD33I-z3p6ieo/manage/uninstall)**.
2. Delete the file in your Google Docs/Drive that is used for storing the Gmail Meter data. The file name is "Gmail Meter Data - Do not delete". **Make sure to empty the item from your Docs/Drive Trash** to permanently delete the file.

Then head over to **http://gmailmeter.com** and hit **Get Started** to **install** the latest version of Gmail Meter.